# CSS частично не подгрузился в GITHUB

Tags: html, css, github

После публикации проекта на github не загружается половина CSS стилей. При этом на виртуальном сервере в VScode стили отрабатываются в полной мере.

Из-за чего такая ошибка происходит?

вот мои ресурсы ссылка на проект: github.com/teosoph/AUGHT-test-task ссылка на публикаю на github: teosoph.github.io/AUGHT-test-task

Прошу помочь разобраться!

[image: код index.html]

[image: как отображается CSS на гитхабе]

[image: как отображено на виртуальном сервере VSCode]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: вот мои ресурсы 

ссылка на проект: https://github.com/teosoph/AUGHT-test-task

ссылка на публикаю на github: https://teosoph.github.io/AUGHT-test-task/

Прошу помочь разобраться!

Comment: Откройте консоль dev-tools в браузере и перейдите во вкладку network, там вы сможете увидеть что именно у вас вызывает проблемы с загрузкой (а их там не мало). У меня например, одни только ваши шрифты с домена `db.onlinewebfonts.com` подгружаются 12сек

Comment: @Pilaton я трошки новичок, можете подсказать, что означают эти ошибки?
проблема возникает из-за шрифтов и svg-шек?